# is it possible to have multiple .then functions?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm dealing with an error here the website runs fine but when I add the extra `.then`it breaks. I was just wondering if this is coded correctly and if not can you help me?

```js
    // list 1
    $scope.get_this_list = function () {
        return SharedFunctions.issuePOSTOBJCmd(url + 'get_list_1' , {})
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.list_one_options = response.data;
            }, function (error) {
                $scope.display_error = true;
                $scope.display_message = 'HTTP ERROR occured. Please check with Web/Dev Admin ' + error;
            });

    };

    // list 2
    $scope.get_that_list = function () {
        return SharedFunctions.issuePOSTOBJCmd(url + 'get_list_2' , {})
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.list_two_options = response.data;
            }, function (error) {
                $scope.display_error = true;
                $scope.display_message = 'HTTP ERROR occured. Please check with Web/Dev Admin ' + error;
            });

    };
    
        $scope.get_list()
          .then($scope.get_this_list()),
           .then($scope.get_that_list());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

these are to populate a drop down box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing the comma between the "thens", like:

```
$scope.get_list()
      .then($scope.get_this_list())
       .then($scope.get_that_list());
```

Answer (score 2):

`then()` is designed to be chained. To use this you should use syntax `then(func1).then(func2).then(func3)`

You can add any amount of then functions. Use `catch()` to process error (at any place of the chain) and `finaly()` to execute code which should be run in any resolution of the chain.